# How do I universally ignore all unicode errors in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

Running python2.7 here.  I am writing a quick and dirty little script to do some web scraping, and I just want the unicode handler to just ignore all unicode errors.

That is, I am totally fine if it just drops whatever characters it can't convert to ascii anywhere in the program.  This is just a throwaway script I just want to get done :-)

Is there some global "ignore" variable I can set?

Thanks!
/YGA

Comment: That depends upon what functions you are calling. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Just a note: If Unicode is causing you problems, Python 3 is usually a better option in the first place. Py2 is just bad at non-ASCII text.

Comment: There's not really an example to give. Imagine code that does all sorts of things with Unicode strings (and often implicitly converts them to ASCII). I just don't want to see any Unicode errors, ever. Just silently ignore the character.

Answer (score 2):

> I am totally fine if it just drops whatever characters it can't convert to ascii anywhere in the program

Then you want to explicitly [create your Unicode objects](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type) from the `ascii` codec, and specify to `ignore` errors:

```python
input = unicode(input_bytes, encoding='ascii', errors='ignore')
```

See the [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) for more on properly handling Unicode.

(And for writing new code, always choose Python 3 or later unless you have an excellent well-formed reason to stay behind.)

Comment: use `text = input_bytes.decode('ascii', 'ignore')`, to avoid associations with `unicode(obj)` form.